# Print to hardcopy using javascript - landscape mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

Print a web page in landscape mode using javascript. While printing, I want to:

1. Set margins
2. Landscape mode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can mark up the size and margins of a printed page with an [**`@page`** CSS rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-box):

```
/* In CSS, not JavaScript */
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
  margin: 42pt 12pt;
}

@media print {
  /* Define print-specific styles here, for example toning down the decoration
     of hyperlinks and removing the navigation. */
  a {color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important;}
  nav {display: none;}
}
```

However, [browser support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)#Grammar_and_rules) is spotty - aside from [prince XML](http://princexml.com/), only IE8+ and Opera support it. If you want precise cross-browser control over printing, consider a (typically server-side) PDF output mechanism.